# Where is the best place to put external service client in Django?

Tags: python, django, client

Is there any best practice to put external service client code in Django?

I want the client to be initialized only once and can be used globally in Django?

For example I want to integrate ClickHouse and Meilisearch into Django, where I can put the clients?